# Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert : PermissionHelper.java not found

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

iam trying to install 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
i have this error:

```
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert..
PermissionHelper not found
```

i don't need to back to an older version of cordova or remove android platform , because it will give me more errors and need to setup all things from scratch.

```
om.megster.cordova.FileChooser 0.0.0 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.0 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.7.2 "Badges"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.1.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.2.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.1.0 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.6.3 "PushPlugin"
cordova -v : 6.4.0
```

anyone know ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"`. Many plugins have it as dependency and sometimes installation can fail. 
 In case of problems with plugins: `cordova platform rm <platform>` and then adding platform again. If you dont want to install all plugins manually, add  entries in `config.xml`.
 In case of compat it will be something like: `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="~1.0.0" />`